# Doctrine and ZF 2, get the last result from a one-to-many relation in the many side

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have two entity, one called news and another one called photoNews, news is one-to-many relation with photoNews, it work great and fine.

When I upload a image, I want to return the last one and with jQuery I´m able to preview the image. That´s the point, I´m not able to retrive the last image only.

How can be possible a one to many get only the recently on the many side?

I searched about DQL, but nothing with great results. My code below:

```
$news = $this->getEm()->getRepository($obj)->find($idParent);
$photoNews = $parent->getPhotos();
var_dump($photoNews);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

$group          = $entityManager->find('Group', $groupId);
$userCollection = $group->getUsers();

$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("birthday", "1982-02-17"))
    ->orderBy(array("username" => Criteria::ASC))
    ->setFirstResult(0)
    ->setMaxResults(20)
;

$birthdayUsers = $userCollection->matching($criteria);
```

The solution is simple, but the problem was that I used var_dump to fetch the result, with var_dump it result to many information and crashed the chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: Well your awnser lies a bit far away from the question you provided. You don't mention birthday at all in your question. You asked for the last entity within a collection. So I assume you should use something like `$userCollection->last()`. See: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html#74-83 And I find it awkward that var dumping an `ArrayCollection` does crash your Chrome Browser :/ You could try to use `var_dump($photoNews->toArray())`

Comment: Thanks! I did not notice it when posted. Thanks for completing the answer.